# how to change a file running from wamp server to xampp server?

Tags: xampp, wamp, wamp-protocol, query-by-example, xampp-vm

I wrote a php script and ran it on wamp server first , later I downloaded xampp and executed the same script . I found xampp server to be more friendly to me and uninstalled wamp but when i try to start my xampp server and run my php script again, It uses the wamp server , though i uninstalled it . I was unable to find solutions online and one solution of using appcmd didnot work . Can anyone else suggest me other options ?

I wrote a php script and ran it on wamp server first , later I downloaded xampp and executed the same script . I found xampp server to be more friendly to me and uninstalled wamp but when i try to start my xampp server and run my php script again, It uses the wamp server , though i uninstalled it . i want my file to execute on xampp server. what should i do now?